# Customize Logout page with ADFS 2.0

Tags: php, symfony, adfs, adfs2.0, simplesamlphp

I am working on an application written in Symfony2 framework. It is integrated to ADFS 2.0 for SSO. The logout is working as expected. It is redirecting user to all  sites that he logged-in. This is a series of redirections. After the signout, browser lands in the ADFS signout page.

Now, I am looking to a different signout behavoir. I want to user to land in a page (in the same symfony2 application) after the signout where he can sign in again clicking a "Sign in" button again.

Has anyone implemented an approach like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where you land after logging out is controlled by IdP and defined by your SingeLogoutService tag which is a part of metadata file. I don't think you will be able to influence that from your (SP) side.

```
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://example.com/adfs/ls/"/>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/adfs/ls/"/>
```

However if you have access to ADFS you can try playin with solution provided in the answer (it describes how to do it) on microsoft forums:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b562c9a5-6d05-4a19-bd39-cb1bf9f77c4a/adfs-and-google-apps-sso-signout-url?forum=winserverDS